# What is the bsdutils package on Debian? What is a "BSD-style Unix system"?

Tags: debian, history, bsd

I stumbled upon the [bsdutils](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bsdutils) package in Debian. The description says:

> This package contains the bare minimum of BSD utilities needed for a Debian system: logger, renice, script, scriptlive, scriptreplay and wall. The remaining standard BSD utilities are provided by bsdextrautils.

Similarly, the description of [bsdmainutils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/bsdmainutils) also mention BSD:

> This package contains lots of small programs many people expect to find when they use a BSD-style Unix system.

I was surprised to see that these packages relates to BSD, in the context of a Linux system.

Do these packages use some code from BSD? What is a *BSD-style Unix system*?

Comment: Some Linux distros actually have had projects to run on BSD, so this is not as far-fetched as it might sound. Debian was one of them, and it looks like their ‘kFreeBSD’ project is still around, albeit in not a particularly great state.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the beginning, there was [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix), which was a product developed by [Bell Labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs) (a subsidiary of [AT&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T_Corporation)). A lot of groups customized their copy and added their own programs, and shared their improvements with others (for pay or for free).

One such group was the [University of California, Berkley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_California,_Berkeley) (UCB). They shared the [Berkeley Software Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) (BSD) under a very liberal license (known today as the original [BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)). Originally, this was a set of additions to the basic Unix. Eventually, they rewrote the complete operating system, so that it could be used without getting a license from AT&T.

Apart from BSD, the main suppliers of Unix operating systems were computer vendors who sold the operating system with the computer. Some kept basing their operating system on the AT&T version. These systems are known as the [System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V) family, because it was based on this version of AT&T Unix. Other vendors used the BSD version. Some made their own, with the goal of being broadly compatible with the two main players (System V and BSD) but each with their own specifics. A “System V operating system” is a system that is more compatible with AT&T Unix. A “BSD operating system” is a system that is more compatible with BSD.

[GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) was another project to make an operating system that could play the same role as BSD: freely available, and with the same kinds of features as Unix. GNU was much more ambitious than BSD, but as a result they didn't manage to do everything they wanted, and in particular they were missing a critical bit: a kernel. In the 1990s, [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) became the de facto standard kernel for GNU, and an operating system based mostly on GNU core programs on a Linux kernel is known as “Linux”, or sometimes “GNU/Linux”.

GNU/Linux has its own history that's independent from System V and BSD, so it doesn't have all the features that all actual System V systems share, or all the features that all actual BSD systems share. Debian's [bsdutils](https://packages.debian.org/bsdutils) and [bsdmainutils](https://packages.debian.org/bsdmainutils) are collections of small programs that are typically present on BSD systems, but not part of the core that is present on all Unix systems.

The `bsdutils` collection is from [util-linux](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bsdutils). They're programs with similar interfaces to the BSD utilities with the same name, but most if not all were written completely independently, and they're distributed under a GNU license. `bsdmainutils` is a collection of programs copied from a BSD collection, still distributed under a BSD license. They're now maintained by Debian, but they pick up some improvements made by BSD distributions.

Comment: Don't forget `bsdgames`, that has my favorite tetris, `tetris-bsd` !

Comment: `bsdmainutils` has been mostly replaced by `util-linux` in Debian 11; the only remnants are `ncal` and `calendar`, everything else comes from `util-linux` now. (As might be expected a lot of the code in the relevant utilities has the same origin.)

Comment: In the before the beginning, there was [multics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics#Influence_on_other_projects)

Answer (score 12):

These are all tools which originally came from BSD (4.4BSD). Their usefulness isn’t based on their origin; they’ve been included in Linux distributions for a long time, and in fact the current packages in Debian use code provided by [`util-linux`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/util-linux) ([source](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/)).

A BSD-style Unix system is one which includes BSD utilities, and possibly BSD libraries; for example, SunOS is a BSD-style Unix system, HPUX isn’t. See [Éric Lévénez’ Unix History](https://www.levenez.com/unix/)  for a family tree showing the lineages.